# Vimdiff/Diff with excluded words (but not lines)

Tags: unix, diff, vim

I need to diff (if possible using vim as a diff front-end) a myriad files, all of which differ (by design) in at least two aspects:

- char* -> char const*
- foo.m_data -> foo

which I don't care about. `diff` allows the exclusion of entire lines with `-I`, but it's possible that a line has both the desired differences, and other differences I need to correct, like so:

```
void foo ( char* bar, int alice )  
---
void foo ( char const* bar, float bob )
```

Does anybody have any idea how to either use diff, preferably in a manner that can be expressed in a vimscript, or another tool, that would find the difference between `int alice` and `float bob`, but not `char*` and `char const*`?

To reiterate and give another example, I don't want to see this:

```
char* bar = foo( (char*)baz );
---
char const* bar = foo( (char const*)baz );
```

because the only change in that line is the `const`s, but I need to see this

```
char* bar, baz = 'A';
---
char const* bar, foo = 'A';
```

because there are other changes *besides* the consts.

Thanks!

Comment: I doubt you'll find any diff program being that customizable *(I use Beyond Compare for most my diffs)*, but what about simply replacing `const*` with `*` and diff the results?

Comment: <duh> fwiw- Beyond Compare **does** allow to add unimportant strings to neglect while doing the comparison...

Answer (score 2):

I've implemented such in my [AdvancedDiffOptions plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4996), which I've just published. This works by filtering the two buffers through `sed`, removing the parts that should be ignored, and only then feeding this to `diff` (through a custom `'diffexpr'`).

For example, to ignore type differences of `char const` vs. `char` in a diff (the `[ ]` is a trick to specify the whitespace before the keyword):

```
:DiffIPattern [ ]const
:DiffIPattern \.m_data
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is more complex than a regular diff. You need a semantic diff. You could checkout:

http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/SmartDifferencer/

http://www.semanticmerge.com/